# Process ID not shown for .NET CLR Memory

Tags: performance, performance-monitor

I am trying to view the process id in perfmon instead of w3wp#1, w3wp#2....etc

I followed the well documented registry change from 
http://weblogs.asp.net/owscott/registry-change-for-perfmon-and-pid-data

however even after restarting the server I still cannot see the process id for .NET CLR Memory. I can see it for other counters.

Your help is greatly appreciated. Thank you very much

gmat

Comment: The Windows 8.x version of Perfmon.exe has an annoying bug, it doesn't always update the Instance listbox properly.  Just as you describe, the list is empty when you know you picked a counter that is instanced.  The workaround is simple, just click another instanced counter and click back.  Always worked for me.

Comment: Thanks Hans, I tried this but it still didnt work for me.

Comment: Any other answers would be appreciated.

Comment: Have you succeed to resolve it?

Answer (score 0):

If you just need to identify the PID of this specific process, you can also find it with:

```
tasklist /v | find "<name_of_the_process>"
```

It should give you an output like:

```
process.exe        **6020** Console        1     10,780 K Running    MACHINE\themarcelor 0:00:00 N/A
```

You can also go to your regular Task Manager, under View >> Select Columns... and tick the PID checkbox.

Comment: thanks theMarceloR but i want to identify the pid of a specific instance of the worker process - w3wp#1 . when i type your command with "w3wp#1" for name_of_the_process I get nothing. If i type w3wp for name_of_the_process I get all instances of the worker process

Comment: Well.. So how about another pipe? e.g., find <name> | find <instance_name>

Comment: all processes are named "w3wp.exe" and the question is about matching the number in Resource Monitor to its processId